# Setting a value for a CSS custom property such that it becomes a "noop"

Tags: css

Please see the code snippet below. I'm looking for a way to set a value for `--foo` such that the button keeps its originally-defined color, red.

```css
:root {
  --foo: ;
}

button {
  background: red;
  
  /**
   * Is there a way to set a value for `--foo` such that
   * this rule does not override the `background: red` rule
   * above?
   */
  background: var(--foo);
}
```

```html
<button>Launch</button>
```

Comment: From what you have shown, any old non-color rubbish in —foo would do, but I suspect there is more to it than that??

Comment: Providing an "invalid value" doesn't seem to work (i.e. setting `--foo` to something like `garbage`). The background is not red, it's white. FWIW, I've been testing on Chrome (latest).

Comment: that's not possible

Comment: @DBS no it won't work with CSS variables, the validation is done after the cascade is resolved so there is no way to get back to "red" whatever you do.

Answer (score 0):

Use an unset `--foo` and provide a fallback value - the first rule can actually be replace with the second for smaller CSS even

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var#syntax

```css
:root {
  --foo;
}

button {
  /*
   * Is there a way to set a value for `--foo` such that
   * this rule does not override the `background: red` rule
   * above?
   */
  background-color: var(--foo, red);
}
```

```html
<button>Launch</button>
```

**Alternate option THIS is probably what you actually meant** since that initial might be anywhere prior:

```css
:root {
  --foo;
}

button {
  background-color: red;
  /* initial value of the property as fallback */
  var(--foo, initial);
}
```

```html
<button>Launch</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can try to refactor my CSS to option #1, but it might not be possible. Option #2 doesn't look quite right - shouldn't `var(--foo, initial);` be `background-color: var(--foo, initial);`? If you update the example to that, it no longer works.

Comment: Yes, I miss-typed. I will look to address this perhaps when I get a bit more time.